# Generate tree from Child category in magento

Tags: magento

[image: category list]

I have the child category name and its ID

as shown in image

ex Mazar-e-Sharif and Herat

how can i generate a tree from child category as shown in image???

i want to generate tree as same as in image

Comment: want to generate tree same as in image

Comment: if you expect the community to solve your tasks, then you should also tell us how much do you want to pay for this.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code, It will helps you.

```
$_rootCatId     = 2;
$_rootCategory  = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_rootCatId);
$_catName       = $_rootCategory->getName();
if($_rootCategory->hasChildren()) 
{
$_collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
                ->addAttributeToSort('position', 'asc')
                ->joinUrlRewrite()
                ->addIdFilter($_rootCategory->getChildren())
                ->load();

foreach($_collection AS $_sub)
{
    $_subCat    = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_sub->getId());

    if($_subCat->hasChildren()) 
    {   
        echo '<li class="leve10 nav-'. $_subCat->getId() .'">';
            echo '<a id="subCatLink">';
                echo '<span>'. $this->htmlEscape($_subCat->getName()) .'</span>
                </a>
         </li>';
        echo '<ul id="subCatUl" style="padding:0px 13px;">';
        $__collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
                ->addAttributeToSort('position', 'asc')
                ->joinUrlRewrite()
                ->addIdFilter($_subCat->getChildren())
                ->load();

        foreach($__collection AS $__sub)
        {
            $__subCat   = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($__sub->getId());
            echo '<li class="leve20 nav-'. $__subCat->getId() .'">
                    <a href="'. $this->getCategoryUrl($__subCat) .'">
                     <span>'. $this->htmlEscape($__subCat->getName()) .'</span>
                    </a>
                 </li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<li class="leve10 nav-'. $_subCat->getId() .'">
            <a href="'. $this->getCategoryUrl($_subCat) .'">
             <span>'. $this->htmlEscape($_subCat->getName()) .'</span>
            </a>
         </li>';
    }
}
}
```